# Bank balance for Schengen visa?

Tags: visas, schengen, indian-citizens, italy, proof-of-funds

My boyfriend and i are planning 10days trip to Italy. So basically he is sponsoring the trip. My bank account does not have sufficient amount. Also we are right now in two different countries. So is there a way to obtain Schengen visa by showing his bank balance along with a letter?

Comment: Likely, no. Since you're not married, residing in different countries, it would be hard to provide his documents for your visa application. I would suggest to obtain a credit card with a sufficient loan limit, European embassies consider such a bank account as a valid solution

Answer (score 3):

Actually, I have done that for my girlfriend before. I sent her my bank statement, letter mentioning that I'll be responsible all the expenses (My bank statement shows enough fund for 50 Euro per days for the entire visit for two people) and my passport. Also, she needed to show bank statement as well but her balance wasn't enough. We weren't married we were just boyfriend and girlfriend.

She submitted everything and they questioned about our relationship a bit, like how we met, how long we have been in this relationship. However, eventually she got the visa. I cannot say for sure that this would work for you as well. I'm just telling you about my personal experience.